# how do i automatically click the link when page loads in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In controller

```
if params[:name]==params[:name]   
  @categories=Category.where(:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id])
  @menus=Menu.where(:category_id=> params[:id]).sorted   
  @cart = current_cart
end
```

In index page:

```
<%@categories.each do |d|%>
<%= link_to d.name ,{:action=>'index',:id=>d.id,:hotel_id=>d.hotel_id},class: "btn-orange" %>       
<%end%>
```

I am getting all the categories and it's respected menu items from database. how do i automatically click the first category link when page loads.

Comment: `if params[:name]==params[:name]` ?? Why dont you redirect at the controller level?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question bluntly, you'll have to [use JQuery to invoke the click event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var loaded = function(){
   $("a.first_link").trigger("click");
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", loaded);
```

--

**Structure**

Needless to say, this does not mean you'll be making a robust, efficient system. Instead, it means you'll be calling an event which you shouldn't need to.

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like your controller is the place where this type of [business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) should occur:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :hotels do
   resources :categories
end

#app/models/hotel.rb
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :menus
end

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_cart

   def index
      @hotel =      Hotel.find params[:hotel_id]
      @categories = @hotel.categories      
      @menus =      @categories.find(params[:id]).menus.sorted
   end

   private

   def set_cart
      @cart = current_cart 
   end
end
```

Comment: If you give us more context, we'll be in a better position to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger` to call action on jquery, as the following:

```
$(documnet).on("page:load ready", function(){
  $("a.first_link").trigger("click");
})
```

You can read more [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), and [load page event](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

use [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) to get/detect the first element(this is what you want) and then click it using jquery

**view file**

```
<%@categories.each_with_index do |d,index|%>

<%= link_to d.name ,{:action=>'index',:id=>d.id,:hotel_id=>d.hotel_id},id:first_"#{index}",class: "btn-orange" %>       

<%end%>

====================js code to click when page is ready============

$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function() {
   //click after 2 seconds when page loads or remove it or use=> $('#first_0').trigger('click'); directly without setTimeout in document.ready()
   $("#first_0").click();
}, 2000);

})//document ends
```